# Как отправлять запросы не выходя из сесси?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, telebot, сессия

У меня проблема как сделать что-бы запрос не отправлялся каждый раз с регистрацией на сайте? Сайт имеет защиту от роботов если более 2 регистраций с одного ip то будет кд. Подскажите мне как работать в пределах одной Session?

```
@bot.message_handler(command=['start'])
def register (message):
   session = requests.Session()
   r = session.get('https://mrush.mobi/login', headers = {
       'User-Agent': user_agent_val
   })
   # Register
   post_request = session.post('https://mrush.mobi/login', {
       'name': name,
       'password': password,
   })

def money(session,message):
   g = session.get("https://mrush.mobi")
   soup = Bs(g.text, 'html.parser') 
   gold_status = soup.find_all('div', class_='cntr lorange small')
   for money in gold_status:
       print("Ваші кошти \nЗолота|Срібла\n" + "     " + money.text)
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Ваші кошти \nЗолота|Срібла\n" + "       " + money.text)
```

[image: Робота]
[image: Код]
Всеравно оно 2 раза входит и все(.
[image: Я не понимаю что парсить тут все меняеться]

Comment: Код урезан, я вызываю money через if message.text == "Money":

Comment: Если post_request = session.post('https://mrush.mobi/login', {'name': 'qwert', 'password': '12345',}, headers = {'Referer': 'https://mrush.mobi/welcome'}), то в ответе (print(post_request.text) вы увидете "Поставьте галочку "я не робот"". При post-запросе не передаете еще один параметр {{"name":"12345", "password": "ttgghhjj", "c956062920": ""}. "c956062920" при каждой сессий он разный, который можно получить при get-запросе спарсив  html.

Comment: Спасибо но тут проблема с парсингом будет. Картинка 3

Answer (score 0):

Получите cookie с запроса и используйте их:

```
resp = requests.get(url)
cookies = resp.cookies
```

Comment: Использовать при отправке запроса?

Comment: да, requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Не знаю может я что-то не так делаю оно так же отправляет з регистрацией по новой(